# Interest Rate in Value Iteration Algorithm

Tags: artificial-intelligence

In the chapter about Value Iteration algorithm to calculate optimal policy for MDPs, there is an algorithm:

```
function Value-Iteration(mdp,ε) returns a utility function
  inputs: mdp, an MDP with states S, actions A(s), transition model P(s'|s,a),
            rewards R(s), discount γ
          ε, the maximum error allowed in the utility of any state
  local variables: U, U', vectors of utilities for states in S, initially zero
                 δ, the maximum change in the utility of any state in an iteration

  repeat
     U ← U'; δ ← 0
     for each state s in S do
         U'[s] ← R(s) + γ max(a in A(s)) ∑ over s' (P(s'|s,a) U[s'])
         if |U'[s] - U[s]| > δ then δ ← |U'[s] - U[s]|
  until δ < ε(1-γ)/γ
  return U
```

(I apologize for the formatting, but I need 10 rep to post picture and $latex formatting$ doesn't seem to work here.)

and also a chapter earlier there was a statement:

> A discount factor of γ is equivalent to an interest rate of (1/γ) − 1.

Could anyone explain to me what does the interest rate (1/γ)-1 mean? How did they get it? Why is it used in the termination condition in the algorithm above?

Answer (score 1):

The reward at t-1 is considered discounted by a factor gamma (y). That is to say, old = y x new. So new = (1/y) * old, and new - old = ((1/y) - 1) * old. That is your interest rate.

I am not so sure why it is used in the termination condition. The value of epsilon is arbitrary, anyway.

In fact, I believe this termination criterion is very bad. It does not work when y = 1. When y = 0, then the iteration should stop immediately, since it is enough to estimate perfect values. When y = 1, many iterations are necessary.